# Message: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, timeoutexception

Im new to python and currently working on an auto submission on a checkout page. I understand that the element is within the iframe hence I have used **`By.Xpath,"//iframe`** instead.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='newCard']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='newCard' and @id='newCard']"))).send_keys("4242424242424242")
```

But im still getting this error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python Scripts\Nike_autologin_autofill_v2.py", line 44, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='newCard']")))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add HTML tag of your iframe?

Answer (score 0):

`"iframe.newCard"` CSS-selector means *iframe node with **class name** 'newCard'*

You need to specify `@class` instead of `@id`. Try to replace

```
"//iframe[@id='newCard']"
```

with

```
"//iframe[@class='newCard']"
```

Comment: i've replaced it with @class but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben did you get TimeOutException on the same line? Share trace log